# How to populate Data using EF Code First and a Seed method

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

The title of my question is fairly simple.  I guess what I'm really having problems with is understanding how my objects relate to each other and how those relationships are stored in the data base.

I have a Team class:

```
public class Team
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

And a Player class

```
public class Player
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual int Number { get; set; }
    public virtual string Position { get; set; }
    public virtual Team Team { get; set; }
}
```

My Data Source Interface

```
public interface ITeamDataSource
{
    IQueryable<Team> Teams { get; }
    IQueryable<Player> Players { get; }
    IQueryable<Coach> Coaches { get; }
}
```

and my DataContext which inherits from DbContext and ITeamDataSource

```
public class TeamDB : DbContext, ITeamDataSource
{
    public TeamDB()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Coach> Coaches { get; set; }

    IQueryable<Team> ITeamDataSource.Teams
    {
        get { return Teams; }
    }

    IQueryable<Player> ITeamDataSource.Players
    {
        get { return Players; }
    }

    IQueryable<Coach> ITeamDataSource.Coaches
    {
        get { return Coaches; }
    }
}
```

In my Seed method I am trying to implement a few teams that have a list of players

```
        context.Teams.AddOrUpdate( t => t.Name,
          new Team { Name = "K1 White"},
          new Team { Name = "K1 Blue" },
          new Team { Name = "2nd Grade White" },
          new Team { Name = "2nd Grade Blue" },
          new Team { Name = "3rd Grade White" },
          new Team { Name = "3rd Grade Blue" },
          new Team { Name = "4th Grade White" },
          new Team { Name = "4th Grade Blue" }
        );

        context.SaveChanges();

        Team K1White = (Team)context.Teams.Where(t => t.Name == "K1 White").First();

        context.Players.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            new Player() { Name = "Alex S", Team = K1White, Position = "LG", Number = 26 },
            new Player() { Name = "Carson B", Team = K1White, Position = "RT", Number = 11 },
            new Player() { Name = "Colton B", Team = K1White, Position = "SUB", Number = 10 },
            new Player() { Name = "Christian H", Team = K1White, Position = "QB", Number = 17 },
            new Player() { Name = "Xander D", Team = K1White, Position = "RB", Number = 00 },
            new Player() { Name = "Zak B", Team = K1White, Position = "RB", Number = 15 },
            new Player() { Name = "Logan A", Team = K1White, Position = "RB", Number = 14 },
            new Player() { Name = "Solomon R", Team = K1White, Position = "TE", Number = 44 },
            new Player() { Name = "Wyatt G", Team = K1White, Position = "RT", Number = 99 },
            new Player() { Name = "Nick K", Team = K1White, Position = "C", Number = 98 },
            new Player() { Name = "Carson M", Team = K1White, Position = "RG", Number = 97},
            new Player() { Name = "Carson H", Team = K1White, Position = "TE", Number = 96 }
        );

        context.SaveChanges();
```

In my controller I am just simply grabbing all the teams and returning the View with them

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var allTeams = _db.Teams;
        return View(allTeams);
    }
```

and in my view I am just trying to create a list of teams, and for each team have a list of players

```
@model IEnumerable<TeamManagement.Models.Team>

<ul>
    @foreach (var team in Model)
    {
        <li>@team.Name</li>
        <ul>
            @foreach (var player in team.Players)
            {
                <li>@player.Name | Position: @player.Position | Number: @player.Number</li>
            }
        </ul>
    }
</ul>
```

When I run this, it fails when it tries to iterate through the players of a team object, because it is null.

**My question basically comes down to this:  What is the right way to handle this?**

I haven't done a lot of work in Databases, nor have a done much EF CF development.  Do I need to load all the players who have a team ID that matches the ID of the team in my controller?  Is my design wrong in the models?  Am I not thinking about it correctly?

Comment: Did you run the seed method using `Update-Database` ?

Comment: Yes, each time I made a change.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be falling foul of something akin to what occurs when you assign an entity to a navigation property then call `Add`. And you may find that you have lots of teams with the same name in the database.

See this for an explanation: [Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx)

Try adding a `TeamID` to Player then do this:

```
var team1 = new Team { Name = "K1 White"};
context.Teams.AddOrUpdate( t => t.Name, team1);
context.Players.AddOrUpdate(
            p => p.Name,
            new Player() { Name = "Alex S", 
                           TeamID = team1.ID , Position = "LG", 
                           Number = 26 }
```

Comment: That was a great read.  I'm actually going to watch her pluralsight course on the Entity Framework to become better versed in EF.  I'll give this a try then update my answer selection.